# Call interface methods in different order

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have one interface with several methods:

```
interface IExample {
 methodA();
 methodB();
 methodC();
 ...
 methodN();
}
```

I also have several implementations of that interface (e.g class A, class B...). I also have HashMap where I put those implementations based on specific key:

```
commands = new HashMap<String, IExample>();
commands.put("key1", new A());
.
.
commands.put("keyN", new N());
```

I use strategy design pattern to fetch each implementation when some event occur:

```
Event event = ...
IExample example = UtilClass.commands.get(event.getKey());
```

and now I am able to call methods on particular implementation:

```
example.methodA();
...
```

The problem is that depending on the event, method call order is different. So, for key1 call order is:

```
example.methodC();
example.methodA();
...
```

but for different key, let's say key2, method call order is:

```
example.methodA()
example.methodC()
...
```

What design pattern or approach I can use in order solve this problem in a easy and clean way? Not to use something like this:

```
 if (example instance of A) {    call order for A... }

 if (example instance of B) {    call order for B... }
```

Comment: You could write a method that calls the other methods in some order, and override it where needed to call them in a different order. That's the normal alternative to `if ( instanceof )` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just simply add another method to your `IExample` interface:

```
interface IExample {
    methodA();
    methodB();
    methodC();
    ...
    methodN();

    execute();
}

class A implements IExample {
    //...
    execute() {
        methodA();
        methodC();
    }
}

...

commands.get("key1").execute();
```

In case, if the `IExample` interface could not be changed, or there are many orders duplicated, you can move the `execute()` method to another interface `IExecutor`:

```
interface IExecutor {
    execute();
}

class Executor1 implements IExecutor {
    private final IExample example;
    public Executor1(IExample example) { this.example = example; }
    execute() {
        example.methodA();
        example.methodC();
    }
}
```

and manage a hash map of `IExecutor` instead of `IExample`:

```
commands = new HashMap<String, IExecutor>();
commands.put("key1", new Executor1(new ExampleA()));
commands.put("key2", new Executor1(new ExampleB()));
...
commands.get("key1").execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:
Create an interface `IExecuteOrder` with a method which says: `executeOrder(IExample example);`

Then implement that `executeOrder` method in different classes, according to your execution order.
Ex.

```
class ExecuteOrder1 implements IExecuteOrder{
  public executeOrder(IExample example){
  example.methodA();
  example.methodC();
  example.methodB();
 }
}
```

Then put those implementation in a map like.

```
Map<String, IExecuteOrder> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", new ExecuteOrder1());
map.put("key2", new ExecuteOrder2());
...
map.put("keyn", new ExecuteOrderN());
```

At last, you'll call your method:

```
map.get("key1").executeOrder(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply declare another method in `IExample` interface:

```
interface IExample {

    methodA();
    methodB();
    methodC();
    // ...
    methodN();

    runInOrder();
}
```

Every class would need to implement this `runInOrder` method, which would just call the `methodX` methods in the required order for that impementation.

I.e. class `A` (that matches `"key1"`) would implement `runInOrder` as follows:

```
@Override
public void runInOrder() {

    this.methodC();
    this.methodA();
}
```

Etc. Then, you might do:

```
Event event = ...
IExample example = UtilClass.commands.get(event.getKey());

example.runInOrder();
```